# When will OpenJDK 9 be available on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, jdk

JDK 9 GA has been out for a while (since September 21, 2017), when will it be available natively on FreeBSD?

Comment: When you write the port for it?

Comment: But why? What advantages does OpenJDK 9 have over Oracle's JDK? I had nothing but problems with programs refusing to run in OpenJDK (different versions) but never ever with Oracle's JDK or JRE for that matter. And still I see no reasons for excessive downvote of this trivial question.

Comment: Bizarrely, one person thinks that this is a request for learning materials (It clearly is not.) and two more think that the answer would be too broad for this format (even though it would be a simple date).

Comment: @ajeh unless you’re Oracle, you can’t port the *Oracle* JDK to another platform; any one can port OpenJDK. Basically, the latter is free software, the former isn’t (in the “libre” sense).

Comment: @StephenKitt And that's it? For a naive me a working JDK is miles ahead of a portable one.

Comment: @ajeh, no, that’s not all there is to it, but in the context of this question it’s a blocker, so I didn’t think it worth while to go into more detail in the comments.

Comment: There is Linux subsystem in FreeBSD.

Comment: @ajeh OK, well for naive me an open implementation is greatly preferable over a closed one ;-). Nowadays anyway the Oracle JDK is largely identical to OpenJDK, the main differences are the font renderer, Flight Recorder, and the handling of security issues. I haven’t had any problem with OpenJDK for a long, long time. (BTW if you don’t @ me I don’t get notified... You are of course free to consider my opinion strongly biased, given my employer; but I speak only for myself.)

Comment: Since you have more than 350 rep, also you have a reopen vote regarding your own questions.

Comment: @ajeh Regarding *Oracle JDK* versus *OpenJDK*, an update: (a) Oracle has now changed their licensing terms, and the Oracle JDK is **no longer free-of-cost** for use in production. (b) Oracle has committed to feature-parity between their Oracle JDK and OpenJDK, even going so far as to donate some of their formerly commercial add-ons (*Flight Recorder* & *Mission Control*) to the OpenJDK project. So, technically, you should see no difference whether running your app on Oracle JDK versus [one of the OpenJDK-based releases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737381/642706).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably never; it looks like the next OpenJDK version which FreeBSD porters will work on [is release 11](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222568), the next release with long-term support.

Of course as Kusalananda mentions in his comment, there’s nothing stopping you from porting OpenJDK 9 to FreeBSD!

Comment: I made my comment tongue in cheek, but the fact is that many open source porting efforts are driven by people needing to use the software they themselves are porting. I can't speak for the maintainers of OpenJDK on FreeBSD specifically, obviously.